# ADLS java sdk data copy

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-java-sdk

Is there a way to copy data over secure channel using the Azure ADLS java SDK? ADLFileOutputStream can be used to steam data to ADLS. Wanted to know if there is a secure API for this.

Answer (score 0):

All our SDKs (Java, .Net, Python etc.) and CLIs (node.js, PowerShell) transmit their data over ADL REST end points.

All communication with the ADL REST end points goes over SSL.

Thus the data in motion is secured.

Comment: I was looking for options to copy data to ADLS using java library and not REST api.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I added more details to the reply.